# ChatServer in java

Tags: java

I did a simple chatserver in the java ... I'm wondering about adding a username to a chat that you need to enter when you enter chat. Also, I do not understand how private messages are sent only to the addressee

If the destination is not logged in to the chat server, the error message should be sent to the sender

Each message sent by the server to the client must be accompanied by the name of the original sender and the time when the message was sent.

Java Code ---> https://dijaspora24.info/?page_id=4123

Comment: This question is very broad. You're asking us to come up with a new implementation.

Comment: What exactly is your Question?

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to show the implementation, since it's a big problem to solve here. However, I will give an idea of how to implement this.

I assume you know how to connect a client to a server (for example by using ServerSocket and Socket).

First, to add the username of a connected client, the server simply has to force the client enter a string to the server as the first thing when it connects to the server.

Second, create a Map to store all clients, where key is the username entered and value is the socket.

Third, when a client want to send a message to another client, some format must be used to send a string that is understandable by the server. When sending a string to another client, the username of the receiving client must be within the string. When the server receives the string, it extracts the username of the receiving client's username and locates the client in the Map by its key. As mentioned, the value of the Map element is the socket instance of the client you want to send to.

To make all of this possible, a thread must be used for each client that listens for input from each client.